# Code after task is not called

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, task

The scenario is that I have text box which I put there URL when the user

type the url and press go I call to the service in TPL ,when the service

is loaded I need to enable the next button(Im working on wizard) if I dont use TPL IsServicevalid get true(bind to command)and the next button is enabled .but in task(TPL) the data is loaded and the next is disabled (even if I put it in the continue) I have noticed that if I click on the page with the mouse anywhere the next turn to enable,do you face some issue like this before?

even if the next button is disabled and I click on it it turn to enable ,all of this happen

just when I use task ,any idea?

this is strange ...:(

```
Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() =>
    {
        //-----get service Data ---------
        try
        {
            GetUsersData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _isValid = false;
            ThrowErrorMessage(e.Message);
        }
    })
    .ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    isServiceValid = true;
```

Comment: I see this "command can execute not updating" problem very often, even in non task related activities. Calling System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() seems to fix it most of the time (i guess that's what is called when you click the ui and it suddenly updates).

Comment: @Dtex- thank you very much !!! propose it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the CanExecute state of commands won't be reflected on the ui untill you click on it.

I don't know why this happens, I personally think this is a behavior that should be changed in the framework itself if possible.

However you can force an update by calling

```
System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

Comment: Thanks Dtex,Just to verify what do you mean fix in the framework?

Comment: I mean that ideally we should not have to call this method directly, but life isn't always ideal :)